# Textbox selected from start

Tags: c#, textbox, focus

I'm trying to write a small program in C# to calculate a equation with a few known variables. A few textboxes (where each variable need to be typed) and a single "calculate" button.

What I'm trying to implement now is that my keyboard cursor is active in a selected textbox when the program starts.

But I can't figure it out.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.focus

Comment: Are doing it for the web or window app? Which platform Java/.Net?

Comment: yes in which language you creating form???

Comment: Mentioned C# in the title. Winforms? WPF? Webforms?

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to inform ya what programming launguage I was using... ups.

Answer (score 2):

For Winforms : View > Tab Order. Set tab order of start textbox to 0.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to inform ya what programming launguage I was using... ups.

Answer (score 1):

write this in your head tag

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById('txtName').focus();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see, you forgot to write down your C# (when i post my first answer).

If you're using C# it would be lot easier thank HTML or PHP.

Simply type this in form_load() :

```
<your textboxname>.Focus()
```

Example :

```
TextBox1.Focus()
```

Comment: Sorry for that. My bad. But yes its C#. I had tried that but it doesnt do anything. I Put in under initializeComponent(); At the moment my button, is the one that is active after the program starts.

Comment: Don't put the code in initializeComponent() class,
First, double click your form.
Then you'll be inside the Form1_Load() class,
put my code there, i guarantee 100% will work.
Hope this helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the order of focus with tabindex

e.g.

```
<input id="thing" tabindex="1" />
```

tabindex is ordinal.  When set, the element with the lowest tab index value will be the first to gain focus.

You can also use tabindex to ensure the next element that the user will hit if he or she presses tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using JQuery.

Simple use that code:
**$('#TextBox').focus();**

where the TextBox is a ID from your TextBox Control.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

So, what programming language that you are using?

In php you could use simple javascript :

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="mytext1" name="mytext1" value="1"><br>
<input type="text" id="mytext2" name="mytext2" value="2"><br>
<input type="text" id="mytext3" name="mytext3" value="3"><br>
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var mytext = document.getElementById("mytext1"); 
mytext.focus(); 

</script>
```

when you load the page it would be focused on "mytext1"

Hope this helpful

Comment: There was an edit, probably while you were typing your answer that the language is c#... lol